# How to upload part of a file with curl?

Tags: http, curl, post

I know how to upload a whole file with curl, like

`curl "http://192.168.1.133/***" -F "file=@./test123"`

to upload `test123`,
what if I upload the first 10 bytes of `test123`, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

curl doesn't provide this feature by itself. You can however achieve the same end goal with using some other tools in combination.

How about cutting out the beginning of the file with `head` and make curl read that part from stdin?

```
$ head -c10 test123 | curl "http://192.168.1.133/***" -F "file=@-"
```

Comment: That's a good way, but I want to know if 'curl' itself has a solution? maybe add a header like `Content-Length` or something else?